# how to apply a function to a matrix of which each element contains a list with different size

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying very hard to figure out how to solve my question in vain. I will appreciate a lot if someone can give me some advices. Thanks a lot.

R returns me a matrix A (dim: 489 x 5) in which every element contains a list with different size, subset of A[1:10, ] showing as follows:

```
      SAMPLE_1     SAMPLE_2     SAMPLE_3     SAMPLE_4     SAMPLE_5       
 [1,] Numeric,1210 Numeric,1210 Numeric,1210 Numeric,1210 Numeric,1210  
 [2,] Numeric,194  Numeric,194  Numeric,194  Numeric,194  Numeric,194   
 [3,] Numeric,212  Numeric,212  Numeric,212  Numeric,212  Numeric,212   
 [4,] Numeric,2519 Numeric,2519 Numeric,2519 Numeric,2519 Numeric,2519   
 [5,] Numeric,1524 Numeric,1524 Numeric,1524 Numeric,1524 Numeric,1524
```

I tried to create a function using a for loop to go through A and to get the average (mean) of each element, but it didn’t work. It just returns the mean of first element. My code is as follow:

[image: The code]

`getMean(A)` gave output :

```
           [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] 
 [1,] 0.7726065   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [2,]        NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [3,]        NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [4,]        NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [5,]        NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Comment: Show the result of dput(x) where x is your input suitably cut down and show the expected output. Do NOT use images.

Comment: or even `array(sapply(A,mean),dim(A))` or `structure(sapply(A,mean),.Dim=dim(A))`

Comment: To Onyambu, Thank you very much. It works !